# Display info from a database on a webpage using php

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to get information from my database displayed in a webpage. Here is my code:

```
<body>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

/*
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db("music" , $con);
*/

$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM music";

$rs = mysqli_query($strSQL, $con);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {

   // Write the value of the column FirstName (which is now in the array $row)
  echo $row['artist'] . "<br />";
  echo $row['title'] . "<br />";
  echo $row['format'] . "<br />";
  echo $row['notes'] . "<br />";

  }
?>
```

Comment: By uncommenting your mysqli_select_db statement, you don't have a db selected.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
I believe you have your query and connection object reversed.

Should be: $rs = mysqli_query($con, $strSQL);

Comment: what is your problem? what is the output. do you have any error?

Comment: What is the name of the database, what is the name of the table?

Comment: You can also select your database as the fourth parameter to `mysqli_connect`.

Comment: too fast, again @Fred-ii-

Comment: @michael It's just another one of "those" questions ;) - *unclear* - you can always modify your answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- exactly...

Comment: Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in E:\xampp\htdocs\php_project\index.php on line 19

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in E:\xampp\htdocs\php_project\index.php on line 26

Comment: You have a few answers below, consult them. @tabmanmatt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `mysqli_`, the connection comes first for everything. Whereas the connection comes as the last parameter with `mysql_` functions and you may have confused those by having used `mysql_` functions in the past and have decided to start using `mysqli_` now.

*Let's start with* where you've commented out:

```
/*
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db("music" , $con);
*/
```

Either you change that to:

```
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($con, "music");
```

Or change:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
```

to:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "music");
```

as I've made it that way below, using all four parameters in one line.

**Important sidenote:**

Make sure that both database and table are indeed called `music`.

If your database is a different name than `music`, then that's what you need to use for the fourth parameter and not the table name.

```
<body>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "music");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM music";

$rs = mysqli_query($con, $strSQL);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {

   // Write the value of the column FirstName (which is now in the array $row)
  echo $row['artist'] . "<br />";
  echo $row['title'] . "<br />";
  echo $row['format'] . "<br />";
  echo $row['notes'] . "<br />";

  }
?>
```

Having used `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` would have signaled the error.

*More precisely:*

```
$rs = mysqli_query($con, $strSQL) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really ask for something, but the answer to your question is:

change this line to:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","music"); // If the db is called music
```

and you need to put this line/variables in another direction:

```
$rs = mysqli_query($strSQL, $con);
```

needs to be:

```
$rs = mysqli_query($con, $strSQL);
```

And put the correct table in your select statement, then it will work.

Comment: *My bad*. I didn't check if you had re-edited your answer before I submitted one as well. Will wait and see what OP says.

Comment: Don't care, if he picks your's let's call it a even for the last question... :)

Comment: LOL! Fair enough ;) either way Michael, OP will get the solution, *hopefully* and that I haven't opened up a "can of *proverbial* worms".

Comment: hehe, right :)  @Fred-ii-